# Artifactory: download all root files of latest published build, non-recursively

Tags: artifactory

I would like to retrieve from artifactory the files that follow this pattern:

```
"my-artifactory-repo/project-name/branch-name/1234/*"
```

Where `1234` is the build number of the latest published build, and where `*` should **not** recurse into folders but just match the immediate files. I use `build-publish` to publish each build under the build name "project-name.branch-name".

I have written a filespec which specifies a "build" but not a build number, causing Artifactory to automatically select the latest published build. This works fine if I simplify the pattern to `my-artifactory-repo/project-name/branch-name/*`, which results in all artifacts for the latest build being downloaded.

However, where I run into trouble is with the requirement to download only the immediate files instead of recursing into folders. So I tried to use a regex as follows.

```
{
    "files": 
    [
        {
            "pattern": "my-artifactory-repo/project-name/branch-name/(\\d+/[^/]+)",
            "build": "project-name.branch-name",
            "recursive": "false",
            "regexp": "true","
            "target": "./artifactory-tmp/"
        }
    ]
}
```

**However, each time I try to use a regex, I get zero results.**

Some other things I've tried which didn't work:

- Not surrounding regex with parentheses
- Using a simpler regex like `..../build.bat` (because currently I have 4 digit build numbers, and I know a build.bat file is there), with or without parentheses
- not using a regex and instead using the pattern `my-artifactory-repo/project-name/branch-name/*/*`. But this causes recursing in spite of "recursive":"false"
- using this search command to retrieve the available build numbers first, so that I can extract the last one and insert it into the filespec. However, there's no way to tell whether the latest build folder is already complete and published, or still currently uploading.

  ```
  jfrog search --recursive=false --include-dirs=true "my-artifactory-repo/project-name/branch-name/"
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The "regexp" option is supported only for the upload command, and not the download command. I believe that the file spec schema under the jfrog-cli documentation shows that. Options that are included in the file specs and are not supported are ignored. This is perhaps something that should be improved.

When the "recursive" option is set to "false" when downloading files, the command indeed avoids recursive directory search. However patterns that include multiple wildcards together with non recursive search, cause some ambiguity in the sense of how deep should the search get. Notice that a single wildcard can include multiple directories. It easy to understand what recursive means when the pattern includes a single wildcard, but with more than one, recursive is practically undefined.

See if you can make your pattern more specific, so that it catches exactly what you need. If this is impossible, consider splitting your pattern into multiple patterns. All patterns can still be included into the same file spec, because "files" inside the spec is a list, which can include multiple pattern and target pairs.

Comment: Thanks, that asymmetry of the regexp option being available only for upload caught me off guard. I have changed my approach now. The reason I was coming at the problem this way, is because I need to migrate a large number of Jenkins "Archive Artifacts" and "Copy Artifacts" steps to use Artifactory instead. I would have preferred to stick as close as possible to those original patterns to avoid introducing new problems. Rethinking each of the patterns to fit Artifactory will be time-consuming.